# Call variables from jQuery in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I call variables defined in jQuery when working in javascript. Basically, I have this:

```
(function ($)
{
    function giveVariables()
    {
        var foo;
        var bah;

        $(document).bind('stuff' , function(e, superFoo, superBah)
        {
            foo = superFoo;
            bah = superBah;
        });

        return {fop: foo, bahp: bah}
    }
})(jQuery);

function needVariables()
{
    var neededVars = giveVariables();
    fop = neededVars.fop;
    bahp = neededVars.bahp;

    *code that uses variables I passed* 
}
```

Obviously, it is not pulling the variables. It is telling me that giveVariables is undefined, but I am not sure why. I am kinda new to javascript, so any information at all would be helpful.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to place the first half of the code in a self-invoking function? You also have to look into variable scope: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/ To make `foo` and `bah` accessible outside the self-invoking function, you have to declare them outside of it.

Comment: The title makes no sense - jQuery *is* [a] JavaScript [library]. One doesn't "define variables in jQuery" and the same *variable scoping* concepts affect all JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `foo` and `bah` in a scope that is not accessible to the function where you need it. it's as simple as that. If you want to to be accessible where you need it, you need to define them in a scope where it would be accessible.

```
//(function ($)
//{

    function giveVariables()
    {
        var foo;
        var bah;

        $(document).bind('stuff' , function(e, superFoo, superBah)
        {
            foo = superFoo;
            bah = superBah;
        });

        return {fop: foo, bahp: bah}
    }
//})(jQuery);

function needVariables()
{
    var neededVars = giveVariables();
    fop = neededVars.fop;
    bahp = neededVars.bahp;

    *code that uses variables I passed* 
}
```

If you want to keep the iife you had originally, you need to attach your `giveVariables` function to the window.

```
(function ($)
{
    function giveVariables()
    {
        var foo;
        var bah;

        $(document).bind('stuff' , function(e, superFoo, superBah)
        {
            foo = superFoo;
            bah = superBah;
        });

        return {fop: foo, bahp: bah}
    }
    window.giveVariables = giveVariables;
})(jQuery);

function needVariables()
{
    var neededVars = giveVariables();
    fop = neededVars.fop;
    bahp = neededVars.bahp;

    *code that uses variables I passed* 
}
```